# A resource instance address is required here. The module path must be followed by a resource instance specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

Changes to a particular module are not being applied. Hence, I wanted to try using `terraform apply --replace` for a particular module. I tried this:

```
 terraform apply -replace="module.moduleName"
```

However, I get an error that:

```
A resource instance address is required here. The module path must be followed by a resource instance specification.
```

Now I am not sure what exactly is the instance address in this case. If it's a path, what path should I use? Should I enter the path from the file where i am running this terraform command to the file where the module is declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource addressing in TF is explain in [docs](https://www.terraform.io/cli/state/resource-addressing#resource-addressing).

Lets say, your module creates an ec2 instance. Then it should be:

```
terraform apply -replace="module.moduleName.aws_instance.web"
```